# FFmpeg disables Window Desktop Manager in my app

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, directshow, aero

I render video using DirectShow & FFmpeg in my app. FFmpeg is only used for decoding of MPEG4/Part2 frames (custom decoder filter). My app does not play audio (only video).

When I lock my PC (Win7 Pro 64bit) with Win+L and then unlock it Windows brings me the following message:

> **The color scheme has been changed**
>
> The following program has performed an action that requires Windows to temporarily change the color scheme to Windows 7 Basic.
>
> ...app name, publisher, pid...
>
> Windows will automatically change the color scheme back to Windows Aero when this program or other programs performing similar actions are no longer running.

I have a possibility of using another custom decoder filter which was developed without FFmpeg, and using it Windows does not show such messages to me.

I ran Aero troubleshooter that detected Desktop Window Manager was disabled.

My main question: Why this message appears after unlocking?

P.S. I'm using ffmpeg mpeg4 decoder, sws_scale from RGB24 to YUV420p. FFmpeg was built only with mpeg4 decoder/encoder, everything else was disabled.

Comment: This issue does not relate to FFmpeg (I hope), issue appears even if I "disable" FFmpeg-related code and libs. This issue relates to Video Render used in DirectShow filter graph. I use CLSID_VideoRenderer, but the issue does not appear with FFmpeg and CLSID_MixingVideoRender9/CLSID_EnhancedVideoRenderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by providing **negative height** (top-down bitmap) in bitmapinfoheader when negotiating media types.
I changed height to be positive (bottom-up bitmap) in my decoder and color scheme of Windows 7 is not touched anymore.